# Extract Final-Recipient from a bounced email

Tags: php, regex

This is the string I have:

```
--A683C6405E1.1403410842/server.abc.com
Content-Description: Delivery report
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; server.abc.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: A683C6405E1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; bouncer@abc.com
Arrival-Date: Tue, 13 Jun 2012 00:03:28 -0400 (EDT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; getthis@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.1


--A683C6405E1.1403410842/server.abc.com
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Return-Path: 
Received: by server.abc.com (Postfix, from userid 517)
    id A683C6405E1; Tue, 17 Jun 2014 00:03:28 -0400 (EDT)
```

I need to extract `Final-Recipient` from this string. The output should be `getthis@gmail.com`.

Comment: You can use the following regex: `Final-Recipient:[^;]+;\s*(\S+@\S+\.\S+)`.

Comment: above regex is not working. can you suggest me again?

Answer (score 0):

`Final-Recipient:\s*RFC822;\s*([\w_.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w-.]+)` or `Final-Recipient:\s*RFC822;\s*(.*)`

The first one has also mail address structure validator, the second one captures anything to the end of the line. I don't know what kind of mail address should be there in Final-Recipient - if there can only be proper mail address both would work. But if there could also be broken mail address (for e.g. abc@abc or *?={gmail.com), the second regex would be the one.

---

Btw, do not forget to set regex to insensitive (PHP: `"/Final-Recipient:\s+?RFC822;\s+?(.*)/i"`). I guess RFC could be either upper or lower case.